# How do the following r.v. notations read in plain English?

Tags: notation, random-variables

> [image]

<sup>***Source:*** *[Schaum's Outline of
Theory and Problems of
Probability, Random Variables, and Random 
Processes](https://www.dca.ufrn.br/~affonso/FTP/livros/Hsu_probabilidade.pdf)*. ***Page-122***</sup>

How do the following notations read in plain English?

- $(Y\le y)=[g(X)\le y]=(X \in D_Y)$
- $F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P[g(X) \le y] = P(X \in D_Y)$
- $\displaystyle F_Y(y)=\int_{D_Y} f_X(x)\, dx$

Comment: For $F_Y$, see [Cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Definition) associated to the real-valued *random variable* $Y$.

Comment: $F_Y(y) = \text {Pr}(Y \le y)$ is the probability that the random variable $Y$ takes on a value less than or equal to $y$. A random variable is defined as a function that maps the *outcomes* of unpredictable processes to numerical quantities (labels), typically real numbers. Thus, $(Y \le y)$ is an *outcome* or *event*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, what is the deal with square brackets?

Comment: What do you mean ? How to "read in plain English" square brackets ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, `What do you mean?` --- I meant: why is it written as $P[g(X) \le y]$? Why not $P(g(X) \le y)$?

Comment: I think it is only a "stylistic" choice ... See [Functions of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I know there is a difference between $[ ]$ and $()$ in case of set theory. Something in the discussion of $closure$ ?